# Laravel 5.1 security

Tags: laravel-5.1

I created something like below. If I enter alert("security flaw!!!!!") between script tags in my input and post it, I get the javascript alert on my browser. Is it normal or is there something missing in my snippet? Am I using CSRF protection correctly? I just started learning Laravel.

routes.php

```
Route::post('settings/generalsettings/changedata', 'UserSettingsController@changeData');
```

userSettingsController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Input;

class UserSettingsController extends Controller
{
public function changeData()
    {
        $variable = Input::get('name99');
        echo $variable;

    }

}
```

generalSettings.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
<body>
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <input type="submit" id="sub">
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // set up jQuery with the CSRF token, or else post routes will fail
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });            // handlers
            $("#sub").click(function (y) {
                y.preventDefault();
                var user_name = $('#name').val();
                $.post(
                        "/settings/generalsettings/changedata",
                        {
                            name99: user_name
                        },
                        function (data) {
                            $('#result').hide().html(data).fadeIn(2000);
                        });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you write script code onto the page, it will be run. There's no cross-site thing there.

Comment: So there is no risk there, isn't it?

Comment: That depends on what you consider a risk. The user can write whatever scripts they want and they may or may not be run the way they intend. You can easily test the things you're worried about.